# Remove rendered data from UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that prints 10 numbers one after another. I also have a button `Clean` that have to remove this 10 numbers when it's clicked. I am not sure how to implement it.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Timeout() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([1])
  const Markup = (
    <ul>
      {message?.map((n) => (
        <li>{n}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (message.length <= 9) {
      setMessage([...message, message[message.length - 1] + 1])
    }
  }, 1000)

  return (
    <div>
      <button>Clean</button>
      <div>{Markup}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If I add `<button onClick={setMessage([])>Clean</button>` I get `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onClick takes in a function. Setting onClick to an arrow function should fix the infinite loop.

```
<button onClick={()=>setMessage([])}> Clean </button>
```